# Asymptotic decay rate of an infinite product of sinc functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics, infinite-product

(*related to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2742261/19661)*)

Consider the function
$$f(x)=\prod_{n=0}^\infty\operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{\pi \, x}{2^n}\right),\quad\color{gray}{x\ge0},\tag1$$
where $\operatorname{sinc}(z)$ denotes the [sinc function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html). The function $f(x)$ has zeros at positive integers, and oscillates with a quickly decaying amplitude. Its signs on the intervals between consecutive zeros follow the same pattern as the [Thue–Morse sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence).
[image: graph of f(x)]

Can we find a real-valued function $g(x)$ (elementary, if possible), such that it is analytic, positive and monotone decreasing (and having monotone derivatives of any order, if possible) and satisfies
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac 1 {t-t_0} \int_{t_0}^t \frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)} \, dx=1\tag2$$
for large enough $t_0$? Or, at least,
$$\color{gray}{\exists A > 0, \, \exists B > A, \, \forall t > t_0,} \, A < \frac 1 {t-t_0} \int_{t_0}^t \frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)} \, dx < B\tag3$$
for large enough $t_0$?

The *"for large enough"* provision means that $g(x)$ is permitted to be not monotone, or have zeros or discontinuities, or be not defined at all for small $t,$ and we only care about its "eventual" behavior.

Empirically, it looks like $g(x)$ should decay faster than any negative power of $x$, but slower than exponentially. I'm thinking something close to $\exp(-\log^2x)$, but perhaps not exactly that.

---

*Update:* Maybe this expansion can be useful:
$$\prod _{n=0}^m \operatorname{sinc}\left(\frac{\pi\,x}{2^n}\right) = \frac{2^{\binom m2}}{(\pi\,x)^{m+1}} \sum_{n=0}^{2^m-1} t_n\,\sin\left(\!\frac {\pi\,m}2+\frac{2n+1}{2^m}\,\pi\,x\!\right),\tag4$$
where $t_0=1,\,t_n=(-1)^n\,t_{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ (the signed Thue–Morse sequence).

Comment: Don't you have the limit in $(2)$ equal to $0$ for $t_0$ an integer?

Comment: @zhw. A choice of $t_0$ does not affect the limit (if it exists), because we are averaging the ratio of functions over an infinite ray. Changing something in a finite initial segment of it does not affect the result.

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. Didn't see $t\to \infty$

Answer (score 3):

---

$\mathbf{\text Definition}$

---

Let
$$R(x) = \prod_{n=0}^\infty\mathrm{sinc}\dfrac{\pi x}{2^n}.\tag1$$

---

$\mathbf{\text{Formulas for } {sinc(\pi z)}}$

---

Using symmetry formulas for the gamma function
$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\dfrac\pi{\sin(\pi z)}\tag2$$
easy to obtain
$$\dfrac{\sin(\pi z)}{\pi z} = \dfrac1{z\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)},$$
$$\mathrm{sinc(\pi z)} = \dfrac1{\Gamma(1+z)\Gamma(1-z)},\tag3$$
$$\ln\mathrm{sinc}(\pi z) = -\left(\ln\Gamma(1+z)+\ln\Gamma(1-z)\right).\tag4$$

Using the Maclaurin series in the form of
$$\ln\Gamma(1+z)=-\ln(1+z)+(1-\gamma)z + \sum\limits_{j=2}^\infty(-1)^j\dfrac{\zeta(j)-1}{j}z^j,\quad |z|<2,\tag5$$
where $\gamma = 0.57721...,$ one can get
$$\ln\Gamma(1-z)=-\ln(1-z)-(1-\gamma)z + \sum\limits_{j=2}^\infty\dfrac{\zeta(j)-1}{j}z^n,\quad$$
$$\ln\mathrm{sinc}(\pi z)=\ln(1-z^2) - \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{\zeta(2k)-1}{k}z^{2k}.$$
Zeta function of the even argument is 
$$\zeta(2k) = \dfrac{(2\pi)^{2k}}{2(2k)!}|B_{2k}|,\tag6$$
where $B_{2k}$ are the [Bernoulli numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html).
Then
$$\ln\mathrm{sinc}(\pi z)=\ln(1-z^2) - \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty c_k z^{2k},\tag7$$
where
$$c_k = \dfrac1{2k}\left(\dfrac{(2\pi)^{2k}}{(2k)!}|B_{2k}|-2\right).\tag8$$

---

$\mathbf{\text{Formulas for R(x)}}$

---

Let us find the sum
\begin{align}
&\ln R_m(x) = \sum_{n=m}^\infty \ln\mathrm{sinc}\dfrac{\pi x}{2^n},\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
&\ln R_m(x) = \sum_{n=m}^\infty \left(\ln\left(1-\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right)^2\right) - \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty c_k\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right)^{2k}\right) =\\
& \sum_{n=m}^\infty \ln\left(1-\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right)^2\right) - \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\left(c_k x^{2k}\sum\limits_{n=m}^{\infty}2^{-2nk}\right) = \\
&\sum_{n=m}^\infty \ln\left(1-\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right)^2\right) - \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{c_k}{1-2^{-2k}}\left(\dfrac{x}{2^m}\right)^{2k}.
\end{align}

The first term can be presented over the [q-Pochhammer Symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html) in the form of
$$\sum_{n=0}^m \ln\left(1-\left(\dfrac{x}{2^n}\right)^2\right) = \ln \left(x^2, \dfrac14\right)_m.\tag{9}$$

This allows to obtain the formulas
$$R(x) = \prod\limits_{n=0}^{m-1}\mathrm{sinc}\dfrac{\pi x}{2^n}\cdot\dfrac{\left(x^2, \dfrac14\right)_\infty}{\left(x^2, \dfrac14\right)_m}\cdot\exp\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\ \dfrac{c_k}{1-2^{-mk}} \left(\dfrac{x}{2^m}\right)^{2k}\right), \quad |x| < 2^{m+1}.\tag{10}$$

Radius of convergence in the formula $(10)$ shows that it gives $R(x)=0$ outside  this radius, such as the Stirling asymptotics. Easy to see that parameter $m$ allows to manage this radius. At the same time, it allows to provide the reqired length of sum.

If the bounds of the required interval are predefined, then paraneter $m$ can be considered as constant. This allows to use the common function for this interval.

For example, for the predefined interval $x=(10,100)$ the value $m=6$ can be chosen. Then formula $(10)$ presents the function $|R(x)|$ as the production of the three factors:

[partial sinc production](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20prod_n%3D0%5E5%7C((pi*x*2%5E(-n))sin(pi*x*2%5E(-n))%2F((pi*x*2%5E(-n))%5E2%2B10%5E-10))%7C,%20where%20x%20in%20(10,100)),

[image: partial sinc production]

[q-Pochhammer ratio](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20(prod_(n%3D5)%5E20%20(1.0-x%5E2%202%5E(-2*n-2)))*sign(64-x),%20where%20x%20in%20(10,100))

[image: q-Pochhammer ratio]

[and the reminder series exponent](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+prod_n%3D1%5E3+e%5E((%7Cbernoulli(2n)%7C%2F(2n)!(2pi)%5E(2n)-2)%2F(1-64%5E(-n))+(x%2F64)%5E(2n)%2F(2n)),+where+x%3D10,+100)

[image: The reminder series exponent]

In the general case, the most convenient way looks using of formula $(10)$ for a piecewise approximation on the required intervals .

Anyway, this allows to take in account the multiplicity of preceeding zeros.

Comment: Anyway, the function $f(x)$ is known to be continuous and analytic, its Taylor–Maclaurin series and Fourier transform are studied pretty well, see, for example, the references in my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2742261/19661).

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov New version. Waiting for comments.

Comment: In formula $(10)$, there is a free variable $m$ on the right, but not on the left -- is it a typo? Also, the summation over $k$ in $(10)$ starts from $k=0$, but the summand contains $c_k$. Looking at the definition $(8)$, we can see that $c_0$ is undefined because it involves a division by zero. Also, there is another division by zero because of the denominator $1-2^{-mk}$.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Of course, this was a typo. The earlier formulas contains $k=1$. Thank you for accuracy.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov By the way. Is known the inequaliity $\dfrac{2(2n)!}{(2\pi)^{2n}}\left(\dfrac1{1-2^{1-2n}}\right) > (-1)^{n+1}B_{2n} > \dfrac{2(2n)!}{(2\pi)^{2n}}, \quad n=1,2,\dots.$

Comment: What about the free variable $m$ in $(10)$?

Comment: I wonder where the scope of the $\prod$ in $(10)$ ends. Is it over only the first factor, or all three?

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Really, $(10)$ contains the ratio of $R(x)=R_\infty(x)$ and $R_m(x),$ and that allows to acheve the nesessary (arbitrary) accuracy. Taking in account the convergency raduis and the required possibly closed form, it does not looking so free.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov It is possible to bound the required series length in $(10)$. At the same time, it gives 0 if $x\ge 2^{m+1}.$ And I don't see any way to  get the asymptotic decay rate as the universal function in the closed form.

Comment: Thank you for the effort (and the bounty is yours), but I do not think this answer brings us significantly closer to resolving my question.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov The problem is solved in closed form for the 'local infinity" settings (see the updated text). I think this is the maximum of possible.